# CSS: How to remain an image being selected in navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the image buttons which is when selected by the user on navigation menu ie: When user hover it will change the button colour (I can do this OK) and the button effect will remain until the user selected the button (This I cannot do).

I try to use "current" or "select" element but it didn't work. Any suggestion?

I also wondering in term of building a navigation menu is it better to use "div" tag or would it be better "li" tag?

So far the HTML looks like this:

```
<body>
<div class="menuBar">
    <div class="home">  <a href="#.php"></a></div>
    <div class="about"> <a href="#.php"></a></div>
    <div class="link">  <a href="#.php"></a></div>
    <div class="contact">   <a href="#.php"></a></div>
</div>
<body>
```

And my CSS is:

```
#menuBar {
    width:525px;
}

.home {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
 }

.home a {
    background: 
    url("http://s20.postimg.org/eb5va917d/Gray_Nav_Over_01.jpg") 
    no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 180px;
}

.home a:hover {
    background: 
    url("http://s20.postimg.org/h6iyh457d/Nav_Over_01.jpg") 
    no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}

.about{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
 }

.about a {
    background: 
    url("http://s20.postimg.org/eb5va917d/Gray_Nav_Over_02.jpg") 
    no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 180px;
}

.about a:hover {
    background: 
    url("http://s20.postimg.org/h6iyh457d/Nav_Over_02.jpg") 
    no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eyy3f/1/).

EDITED: I have seen some people done it in JavaScript but I'd like to see it done in CSS preferably (Although you can show me other alternative in JQuery or other way)

Comment: Jsfiddle you provided doesn't work. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Eyy3f/2/

Comment: So what's the issue. Can you please explain again?

Comment: I can work out the hover part but the problem is when user selected the button I'd like the button remain as it means active / being selected.

Comment: You'd need to add "selected" or similar to the selected menu item, and style it that way.

Comment: Yes I could done ie: `.home a.select { 
  background: url("ttp://s20.postimg.org/h6iyh457d/Nav_Over_01.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; 
}` -- But then the that isn't achieve what I need as only the HOME will be selected (Highlight)

Answer (score 0):

**Focus**

element:focus is the [pseudo class](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3afocus) (.css selector) you are looking for.

Study here for more details : [6.6.1.2. The user action pseudo-classes :hover, :active, and :focus](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act)

> Interactive user agents sometimes change the rendering in response to
>   user actions. Selectors provides three pseudo-classes for the
>   selection of an element the user is acting on.
>
> - The :hover pseudo-class applies while the user designates an element with a pointing device, but does not necessarily activate it.
>     For example, a visual user agent could apply this pseudo-class when
>     the cursor (mouse pointer) hovers over a box generated by the element.
>     User agents not that do not support interactive media do not have to
>     support this pseudo-class. Some conforming user agents that support
>     interactive media may not be able to support this pseudo-class (e.g.,
>     a pen device that does not detect hovering).
> - The :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user. For example, between the times the user presses
>     the mouse button and releases it. On systems with more than one mouse
>     button, :active applies only to the primary or primary activation
>     button (typically the "left" mouse button), and any aliases thereof.
> - The :focus pseudo-class applies while an element has the focus (accepts keyboard or mouse events, or other forms of input).

Try this css :

```
.about a:active,.about a:focus {
    background: url("path to your active-focus image") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Here, i [updated your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubw8T/) so you get a live example.

Comment: thanks for the feedback - I have tried to changed the DIV into LI and run it as you suggested - but it still not working. Any idea? Here is the latest working test: http://jsfiddle.net/Eyy3f/5/  - I am wondering if it would be better to place "current" tag in HTML instead?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's good have have `LI` as to it's like conforming to patterns in code.

Also it's recommended by W3C and that's how they build their samples: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_multiple_pages_with_navigation_menus

As for code specific issue. You need to create active class in the CSS and have it added to you link onClick event:

> CSS

```
.activeState {
    background:url("http://s20.postimg.org/h6iyh457d/Nav_Over_01.jpg") 
    no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

If the site structure is all static then when you land on Home.php, set the class for Home link to **activeState**. Similarly, when you land on other pages (say for example on 
the About page) assign **activeState** class to About link.